# Getting stdout and stderr streams from a docker container in Node.js

Tags: node.js, docker

I am using `dockerode` library and I want to create a container, execute a (single) command in that and get back (separately) the standard output and standard error of that command.

So far I am able to get the *stdout*, but I had no luck with *stderr*. I have found a lot of ways in *Github* issues, but none of those worked.

The code I have is (I am using promises and coroutines to avoid callbacks):

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const coroutine = Promise.coroutine;
const Docker = require('dockerode');

const docker = coroutine.promisifyAll(new Docker());

const foo = coroutine(function*(){

    let container = Promise.promisifyAll(yield docker.createContainerAsync(/*...*/));

    yield container.startAsync(/*...*/);

    const execOpts = {Cmd: /*...*/, AttachStdout: true, AttachStderr: true, Tty: true};
    const exec = Promise.promisifyAll(yield container.execAsync(execOpts));                      
    const stream = yield exec.startAsync();


    let data = [];
    stream.on('data', chunk => {
            data.push(chunk);
    }); 

    stream.on('end', () => {
        stdoutData = Buffer.concat(data).toString()
    });


    let executionData = yield exec.inspectAsync();
    while (executionData.Running) { executionData = yield exec.inspectAsync(); }                                                         

    return {
        stdout: stdoutData,
        stderr: 
    }

});
```

**Note**: In [dockerode's npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode) there is this example for achieving what I want, but I cannot find out what global object `process` is and how to use it in my code:

```
//tty:true 
docker.createContainer({ /*...*/ Tty: true /*...*/ }, function(err, container) {

/* ... */

container.attach({stream: true, stdout: true, stderr: true}, function (err, stream) {
  stream.pipe(process.stdout);
});

/* ... */
}

//tty:false 
docker.createContainer({ /*...*/ Tty: false /*...*/ }, function(err, container) {

/* ... */

container.attach({stream: true, stdout: true, stderr: true}, function (err, stream) {
  //dockerode may demultiplex attach streams for you :) 
  container.modem.demuxStream(stream, process.stdout, process.stderr);
});

/* ... */
}

docker.createImage({fromImage: 'ubuntu'}, function (err, stream) {
stream.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [.demuxStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode#helper-functions):

```
demuxStream - demux stdout and stderr
//demuxStream(stream, stdout, stderr) 
container.attach({
  stream: true,
  stdout: true,
  stderr: true
}, function handler(err, stream) {
  //... 
  container.modem.demuxStream(stream, process.stdout, process.stderr);
  //... 
});
```

The [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process)  object is a global variable representing your current process:

> The process object is a global that provides information about, and control over, the current Node.js process.

[process.stderr](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stderr)
and [process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)
are [Writeable Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams) representing your current process STDOUT and STDERR:

> The process.stderr property returns a stream connected to stderr (fd 2). It is a net.Socket (which is a Duplex stream) unless fd 2 refers to a file, in which case it is a Writable stream.
>
> The process.stdout property returns a stream connected to stdout (fd 1). It is a net.Socket (which is a Duplex stream) unless fd 1 refers to a file, in which case it is a Writable stream.

I.e. the example above will just redirect the container's streams to the STDERR and STDOUT of your current process. But you are free to use any other Writeable Streams instead.